# Bash Выборка по дате и по get запросу CentOS

Tags: grep, awk

Есть файл-журнал сайта `text.log`.

Из него нужно сделать выборку по дате, по запросу `get`, ответ сервера не `HTTP 403` и не `HTTP 404`.

Каков должен быть синтаксис команды?

Пример содержимого файла:

> 37.55.12.210 - - [16/Jan/2014:17:38:21 +0200] "anchor.in.ua" "GET /mechanical?$
>
> 178.44.166.223 - - [16/Jan/2014:17:38:21 +0200] "b-56.ru" "GET /company/divany$
>
> 83.167.122.26 - - [16/Jan/2014:17:38:21 +0200] "gmod-play.ru" "GET /index.php?$
>
> 157.55.32.80 - - [16/Jan/2014:17:38:22 +0200] "htcunlockingservice.com" "GET /$
>
> 157.55.32.80 - - [16/Jan/2014:17:38:22 +0200] "htcunlockingservice.com" "GET /$

Comment: cat text.log | grep %дата% | grep GET

Comment: Спасибо. Буду пробовать. ещё есть условие 
◦ответ сервера не HTTP 403 и не HTTP 404

Comment: (не помню, как задается или-паттерн для грепа, поэтому так)

    cat text.log | grep %дата% | grep GET | grep -v 404 | grep -v 403

Comment: В конце всего этого результирующая выборка должна быть сохранена в файл, и каждая строка должна содержать только IP адрес, дату, время, имя сайта.

Comment: @SergioUser, дополните вопрос. 

Поместите в нем для примера  несколько строк лога.

Comment: Что-то в таком духе

     grep $date $file | grep GET | grep -v 'HTTP.*40[43]' | awk '{print $1 " " $4 $5 " " $6}'

или так

     grep $date $file | grep -v 'HTTP.*40[43]' | awk '$7 ~/GET/ {print $1 " " $4 $5 " " $6}'

вывод (stdout) можете перенаправить в нужный файл.

Comment: Спасибо,работало, а сейчас не могу вообще скопировать данные.Файл создаёт но пустой.

cat access.log | grep 16.01.2014 | grep GET | grep -v 404 | grep -v 403 >>test.log

Comment: @SergioUser мне кажется, или у вас таки дата в формате 16/Jan/2014

Comment: @SergioUser, почему-то думал, что всем будет очевидно, что вместо `$date` и `$file` надо подставить актуальные данные.

Например:

    grep  16/Jan/2014 ./access.log | grep -v 'HTTP.*40[43]' | awk '$7 ~/GET/ {print $1 " " $4 $5 " " $6}'

Comment: Спасибо большое!)Работает! новичок в этом деле)Спасибо всем кто помогал)всего вам хорошего ребята!

Answer (score 1):

ответ из комментария к вопросу.

Например:

```
$ grep 16/Jan/2014 ./access.log | grep -v 'HTTP.*40[43]' |\
 awk '$7 ~/GET/ {print $1 " " $4 $5 " " $6}'
```